# Measure the traffic on blog pages from google ad campaign pages

Tags: events, tags, google-tag-manager

I want the measure if users who land on my pages from google ads campaign are going to my blog post pages.

```
for example:
landing page - start.domain.com
next - domain.com
then - domain.com/blog
and finally - domain.com/blog/blog_post_page
```

How should the trigger in GTM look like?